# QMYSQL driver not loaded Qt 5.6 Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, qt, ubuntu

i know that these question asked many times but i try all solution here and from another site but all not working for me what i try is 
**1 - install libqt5sql5-mysql 

2 - install libqt4-sql-mysql 

3 - use QPluginLoader to load sql driver 

4 - copy the folder of sql driver to my debug folder** 


 
***QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7*** 



i have this problem on windows i solve it by using mcsv 64 it doest work for 32 or for mingw compiler but i dont know how to solve this problem on linux 

 
my os is 

 
- **ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit** 

 - **Mysql compile machine is x86_64**

code i use to connect to database

```
QSqlDatabase dp = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","first");
dp.setDatabaseName("Test");
dp.setHostName("localhost");
dp.setUserName("root");
dp.setPassword("root");
dp.setPort(3306);
if (dp.open()){
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"Succsefull","Connect To Mysql");
}
else{
    QMessageBox::critical(nullptr,"Error",dp.lastError().text());
}
```

Comment: "libqt4-sql-mysql" will definitely not help with Qt 5. run ldd on the mysql plugin to see if there are dependencies missing.

Comment: can you write the cmd how to do that sorry i am beginner in linux os and thank you

Comment: `ldd libqsqlmysql.so`, check the list of required library for entries that are “not found”.

Comment: ok i get a list and i have some dependencies missing what i should do know

Comment: Install the dependencies?

Comment: libmysqlclient_r.so.16   / libssl.so.10 / libcrypto.so.10  This is written in front of them they are not found , when I check with ldd libqsqlmysql. so

Comment: Can you tell me how to install these dependencies I use sudo apt-get install and name of dependencies and try another one is apt-get -f install and thank you

Comment: @hello, could you show us what returns from `ls -ls/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysql*?

Comment: Nothing I try it and I get  > I can upload a photo to my question if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the sqldrivers folder to your debug folder and it should work. Else, try:

```
$ cd /opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers 
$ ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 libmysqlclient_r.so 
$ ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 libmysqlclient_r.so.16
```

Comment: Thank You for your Replay, i try put sqldrivers in my debug folder and not work and try the command you put here and try copy it again and same problem

Answer (score 0):

you can install qtcreator from apt because it has some dependencies that  required for programming

```
sudo apt install qtcreator
```